# Expires headers on AppHarbor

Tags: appharbor

Is there an easy way to add expires headers to static content coming from an appharbor site? I have a bunch of images, css and javascript files which have no expiry set and are holding me back on yslow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work since it collides with AppHarbor's machine level config which I had to learn the hard way.